# display image as response to jQuery ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, base64, encode

I was trying to display image as response to jQuery ajax request:

> php code:

```
    <div id="r_part">
    <img src="reports.php" alt="Report" />
    </div>
```

> jQuery code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "html",
        url: "reports.php",
        data: ({post_year: selected_year}),
        success: function(response){
            $("#r_part").html("<img src=" + base64encode(response) +" />");
        },
        error: function(){
            $("#r_part").html('Oops! Something wrong ...');
            }
    });
```

The php part works fine. But, the $.ajax part is not working for me! It provides an output like below:

[image]

Whats wrong with what I'm doing !!! Any help is highly appreciated...

Saiful

Comment: Why do you need base64encode to encode the response?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the response without the base64encode function being called?

Comment: image has a wrong extension of file what is the purpose of it?

Comment: You don't have a full data URI unless it begins with `data:image/png;base64,` before the encoded data.

Comment: Example of fiddle with base64 URI (http://jsfiddle.net/casiano/xadvz/) .. Make sure your response from reports.php is base64 and then there is no need to encode it as you do. It depends. As mentioned above, base64 decoded data starts with data:image/(gif,png,jpeg ect)  ..

Comment: Also try to make an console.log(response) in your success .. this will give you the reponse from your call (Chrome press F12 to get the debugger console)

Answer (score 0):

try this one while you converting you have not added "data:image/gif;base64,"
so, might be showing that..

```
$("#r_part").html("<img src='data:image/gif;base64," + base64encode(response) +"' />");
```